# How do I approach the tech web?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I'm a veteran Civilization V player, but I'm having difficulty with the huge tech-web in Civilization: Beyond Earth. The fan-out is just too big: I start out with like 8 unlocked options, and it seems that every non-leaf one opens like 4 more.

I've installed [Colorful Tech Web](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=332436665) and [More Tech Filters](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=335768661) but I'm still getting lost whenever I need to make a choice, especially in the early game (it gets easier in the late game when I'm mostly after specific things).

In Civilization V the tech tree had 4-5 lanes and I mostly had a feeling of where stuff would be: naval at the top, then culture/religion, then science and food, then production and cavalry and finally infantry and artillery. Roughly. I can't figure out any equivalent system in Beyond Earth - everything feels just scattered randomly all over the place.

Maybe I just need more practice to start feeling my way around, but I'd appreciate any general tips that will help me with that, and I'd especially like to know whether I can characterize directions in the tech-web similar to the way I have characterized lanes in CiV.

Answer (score 4):

The new tech web is a little harder to get used to, but it opens up the tech a lot more and makes more sense given that you're not having to, say, invent counting before you can open a bank.

Typically, while you're learning your way around the web, there are three goals:  In the short-term, you want things that will either immediately benefit you or raise your science production.  In the mid-term, you're looking for your affinity of choice and its thematic technologies.  In the long-term, you want your affinity's really big guns, like Harmony's "heal in miasma instead of taking damage".

Pay attention to your science output and look at how many turns particular techs will take to research, and then decide on your priorities.  Remember that the further a technology is from center, the more it will cost.  After slogging through a long, slow upgrade, snag a handful of cheap ones from around the center.

The biggest thing is really just choosing an affinity.  Then you can just work on paths to that affinity's experience points on the web until you get sidetracked by a must-have upgrade.

While each direction on the web has a certain general feel, I don't think any major generalizations can be made.  No up=science, down=military type categories, although I could easily be wrong about that (it's been a while since I played).

Comment: The techs/orientation are indeed a bit biased. There are some odd entries everywhere (especially considering technologies unlocking several things), but if I remember right, down would be growth/expansion, left would be military, right construction and up science/support (orbitals). But I could be wrong there, it's been a bit for me as well.